# How to add data into JWT Token in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, jwt

I'm trying to create an authentication system. For this purpose, I want to store user ID in JWT token, so I can know which user which.

I created my JWT token like in below;

```
var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secret key"));//token secret key

var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

var tokenOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                        issuer: "https://localhost:44309/",
                        audience: "https://localhost:44309/",
                        claims: new List<Claim>(),
                        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
                        signingCredentials: signingCredentials
                    );
var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenOptions);

return Ok(new { Token = tokenString });
```

But I couldn't find a way to import user id into this. I tried to add another parameter to `tokenOptions` like `user:{ "id": user.ID},` but I couldn't add it since it's not a real parameter.

```
var tokenOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                        users:{ "id": user.ID},
                        issuer: "https://localhost:44309/",
                        audience: "https://localhost:44309/",
                        claims: new List<Claim>(),
                        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
                        signingCredentials: signingCredentials
                    );
```

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add it to `claims` like this:

```cs
var tokenOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                        issuer: "https://localhost:44309/",
                        audience: "https://localhost:44309/",
                        claims: new List<Claim>() { new Claim("id", user.ID) },
                        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
                        signingCredentials: signingCredentials                       
                    );
```

The resulting token will look like this:
[image: JWT token with id claim]